# Ninject - System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ioc, ninject

Estou com o erro;

> Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor
>   sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual
>   solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da
>   exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de
>   exceção abaixo.
>
> Rastreamento de Pilha:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido
>   para este objeto.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +247    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'CarrinhoDeCompras.UI.Controllers.OrdersController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +191    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Estou usando o Ninject para fazer a IoC, mas não sei o que fiz de errado nas configurações.

```
  [assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(CarrinhoDeCompras.UI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(CarrinhoDeCompras.UI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace CarrinhoDeCompras.UI.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using CarrinhoDeCompras.Infra.CrossCutting.IoC.Modulos;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Load(new ModulosNinject());
        }
    }
}
```

E no ModulosNinject tenho configurado todas as dependências..

```
using Ninject.Modules;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Application.Interfaces;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Application.Services;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Domain.Interfaces.Repositorios;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Domain.Interfaces.Services;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Domain.Services;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Infra.Data.EF.Repositorios;

namespace CarrinhoDeCompras.Infra.CrossCutting.IoC.Modulos
{
    public class ModulosNinject : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind(typeof(IAppServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(AppServiceBase<>));
            Bind<IAppServiceCategories>().To<AppServiceCategories>();
            Bind<IAppServiceCustomerDemographics>().To<AppServiceCustomerDemographics>();
            Bind<IAppServiceCustomers>().To<AppServiceCustomers>();
            Bind<IAppServiceEmployees>().To<AppServiceEmployees>();
            Bind<IAppServiceOrderDetails>().To<AppServiceOrderDetails>();
            Bind<IAppServiceOrders>().To<AppServiceOrders>();
            Bind<IAppServiceProducts>().To<AppServiceProducts>();
            Bind<IAppServiceRegion>().To<AppServiceRegion>();
            Bind<IAppServiceShippers>().To<AppServiceShippers>();
            Bind<IAppServiceSuppliers>().To<AppServiceSuppliers>();
            Bind<IAppServiceTerritories>().To<AppServiceTerritories>();

            Bind(typeof(IServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(ServiceBase<>));
            Bind<IServiceCategories>().To<ServiceCategories>();
            Bind<IServiceCustomerDemographics>().To<ServiceCustomerDemographics>();
            Bind<IServiceCustomers>().To<ServiceCustomers>();
            Bind<IServiceEmployees>().To<ServiceEmployees>();
            Bind<IServiceOrderDetails>().To<ServiceOrderDetails>();
            Bind<IServiceOrders>().To<ServiceOrders>();
            Bind<IServiceProducts>().To<ServiceProducts>();
            Bind<IServiceRegion>().To<ServiceRegion>();
            Bind<IServiceShippers>().To<ServiceShippers>();
            Bind<IServiceSuppliers>().To<ServiceSuppliers>();
            Bind<IServiceTerritories>().To<ServiceTerritories>();

            Bind(typeof(IRepositorioBase<>)).To(typeof(RepositorioBase<>));
            Bind<IRepositorioCategories>().To<RepositorioCategories>();
            Bind<IRepositorioCustomerDemographics>().To<RepositorioCustomerDemographics>();
            Bind<IRepositorioCustomers>().To<RepositorioCustomers>();
            Bind<IRepositorioEmployees>().To<RepositorioEmployees>();
            Bind<IRepositorioOrderDetails>().To<RepositorioOrderDetails>();
            Bind<IRepositorioOrders>().To<RepositorioOrders>();
            Bind<IRepositorioProducts>().To<RepositorioProducts>();
            Bind<IRepositorioRegion>().To<RepositorioRegion>();
            Bind<IRepositorioShippers>().To<RepositorioShippers>();
            Bind<IRepositorioSuppliers>().To<RepositorioSuppliers>();
            Bind<IRepositorioTerritories>().To<RepositorioTerritories>();
        }
    }
}
```

Minha classe OrdersController

```
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Application.Interfaces;
using CarrinhoDeCompras.Domain.Entidades;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CarrinhoDeCompras.UI.Controllers
{
    public class OrdersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppServiceOrders _AppServiceOrders;

        public OrdersController(IAppServiceOrders appService)
        {
            _AppServiceOrders = appService;
        }

        // GET: Orders
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var OrdersViewModel = _AppServiceOrders.GetAll();
            return View(OrdersViewModel);
        }

        // GET: Orders/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var OrderDetailsViewModel = _AppServiceOrders.GetById(id);
            return View(OrderDetailsViewModel);
        }

        // GET: Orders/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Orders/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Orders orders)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _AppServiceOrders.Add(orders);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(orders);
        }

        // GET: Orders/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var ordersViewModel = _AppServiceOrders.GetById(id);
            return View(ordersViewModel);
        }

        // POST: Orders/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Orders orders)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _AppServiceOrders.Update(orders);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(orders);
        }

        private byte[] SetLogotipo(HttpPostedFileBase logotipo)
        {
            var bytesLogotipo = new byte[logotipo.ContentLength];
            logotipo.InputStream.Read(bytesLogotipo, 0, logotipo.ContentLength);
            return bytesLogotipo;
        }

        // GET: Orders/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var categoriesViewModel = _AppServiceOrders.GetById(id);
            if (categoriesViewModel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(categoriesViewModel);
        }

        // POST: /Movies/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            _AppServiceOrders.Remove(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode postar o código do controller OrdersController?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema estava na diferença nas versões do Ninject entre a app UI e a Infra

Comment: Beleza, meu....